# No Audio Ubuntu 20.04 Macbook Pro

Tags: sound, macbook, 20.04

I just recently upgraded to 20.04 from 19.10 doing a complete reinstall and now my sound is not working. I've already tried to force reload alsa and also to modify the grup boot options to include "snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0" as per [this tip from superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/1509312/sound-stopped-working-after-upgrading-to-linux-5-4-intel-hd-audio). Here is the output from inxi -SMA

```
System:    Host: lokiLinux Kernel: 5.4.0-26-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Gnome 3.36.1 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: Apple product: MacBookPro13,1 v: 1.0 serial: <superuser/root required> 
           Mobo: Apple model: Mac-473D31EABEB93F9B v: MacBookPro13,1 serial: <superuser/root required> UEFI: Apple 
           v: 243.0.0.0.0 date: 01/31/2020 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Device-2: Broadcom and subsidiaries 720p FaceTime HD Camera driver: bdc-pci 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-26-generic
```

and here from lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Iris Graphics 540 (rev 0a)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:15.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #2 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1d.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #10 (rev f1)
00:1e.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO UART Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:1e.3 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO SPI Controller #1 (rev 21)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Mass storage controller: Apple Inc. S3X NVMe Controller (rev 11)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4350 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 05)
03:00.0 Multimedia controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries 720p FaceTime HD Camera
04:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Alpine Ridge 4C 2015] (rev 02)
05:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
05:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
05:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
05:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
06:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
07:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
```

any ideas how to fix this issue?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Cheers

Comment: Hi.. Did you succeed?